# Beginner at Python - problem with inquirer

Tags: python

I have just started learning Python and I am stuck with the code (below). I don't know what is wrong but I am unable to choose the medicine and RDV keeps showing twice. Any help?

```
list = [inquirer.List(
  "Medicine",
  message="Choose from the given list",
  choices=("RDV", "MOL", "TCZ", "DEX"),
),]

answer = inquirer.prompt(list)

print (answer["Medicine"])
```

Comment: Please encode the python code with CTRL+K. How inquirer was defined ?

Comment: unrelated tip: don't overwrite the built-in `list` object

Comment: Instead of assuming you know what's in `answer`, first start by logging `answer` in its entirety. What's actually in it? And also, yes, don't name something `list`, that's a python built-in name and is going to lead to unnecessary headaches later. Use a name that reflects what it actually is, like `medication_list`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from PyInquirer import prompt

questions = [
    {
        'type': 'list',
        'name': 'Medicine',
        'message': 'Choose from the given list',
        'choices': ["RDV", "MOL", "TCZ", "DEX"]
    }
]

answers = prompt(questions)
print(answers)
```